# Active Record Update All JSON Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

So I have a model `Item` that has a huge postgresql JSON field called `properties`. Most of the time this field does not need to be queried on or changed, however we store `price` in this field.

I'm currently writing a script that updates this `price`, but there's only a few unique `prices` and thousands of `Items` so in order to save time I have a list of `Items` for each unique `price` and I'm attempting to do an update all:

`Item.where(id: items).update_all("properties->>'price' = #{unique_price}")`

But this gives me:

`syntax error at or near "->>"`

Is there a way to use update all to update a field in a postgres JSON field?

Comment: Why not update the whole field with normal json? `Item.where(id: items).update_all("properties = #{{ key: 1, value 1}.to_json}")`

Comment: Would this not overwrite the entire json field with only the price field?

Comment: As I say why not ? You're using operator `->>` it is for quering json, not for updating.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to use `jsonb_set()` function, here **is an example**:

```
Item.where(id: items).
     update_all(
       "properties = jsonb_set(properties, '{price}', to_json(#{unique_price}::int)::jsonb)"
     )
```

This would preserve all values and update only one key.

Read [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this

```
Item.where(id: items).each do |item|
  properties = item.properties
  item.update(properties: properties.merge({
    price: unique_price
  }))
end
```

The keyword `merge` will override the value of the key provided with the new value ie unique_price

Merge documentation is [here](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/merge)

Comment: Unless you're trying to do an update of a million records and this would crush the system by looping through each one individually.

Comment: yeah no dont do this

Answer (score 0):

What I came up with based on @Philidor's suggestion is very similar but with dynamic bindings:

```
assignment = ["field = jsonb_set(field, '{ name_of_the_key }', ?)", value.to_json]
scope.update_all(scope.model.sanitize_sql_for_assignment(assignment))
```