# How to update different json (jsonb) attributes asynchronously with rails and postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a large json object stored in a postgres table column, an example of the schema is like this:

```
create_table “document” do |t|
    t.jsonb “data”, default: []
end
```

At the moment I’m updating json in the column like so:

```
# find document in rails then…
doucment.data[‘some_attribute’][2][‘another_attribute’] = 100
doucment.save
```

However I write this json attribute many times and sometimes data becomes lost because if two calls are writing it at the same time, then the whole object will be saved or over written with the current objects old data.

For example if there’s two different saves going through at the same with the following

Save 1:

```
doucment.data[‘some_attribute’][2][‘another_attribute’] = 100
doucment.save
```

Save 2:

```
doucment.data[‘some_attribute’][2][‘different_attribute’] = 200
doucment.save
```

then either one of the attributes data will be lost because the other one will save it’s json but with old data that hasn’t been refreshed yet.

What is the best way to go about making both calls save the new data correctly.

Is there any json method that can just go in and update one attribute, like `update_attribute` but for a jsonb attribute?

Comment: What rails version are you using?

Comment: Did my answer work?

Comment: @ErvalhouS it's rails 5.2.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Postgresql has the `jsonb_set` method. You can update your model using this method.

With this code, the record is updated in a single query:

```
Document.where(id: document.id).update_all(
  "data = jsonb_set(data, '{some_attribute,2,another_attribute}', to_json(#{your_int_value}::int)::jsonb)"
)
```

[Related postgresql document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html)

[Answer that helps me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51658104/2190621)

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately, it's saying a column with name of the int_value doesn't exist.

Comment: This worked great in the end with some updates thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because you update the `document` asynchronously, it has nothing to do  with the attribute being a json.

The right thing to do here would be to lock the model before modifying it, that way it won't be overridden, but updated one step at a time.

Try the following:

`Document.lock.find_by(...)`

[ActiveRecord::Locking::Pessimistic](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html)